# FIFA approved sensors for Soccer

Tags: football, technology, fifa

There are many [dedicated sensors available](http://gadgetsandwearables.com/2018/02/02/soccer-training-sensor/) for soccer games and major clubs have stated to use them. Are all these sensors (as listed in the link) approved by FIFA? I know that FIFA has approved **Goal Line** and **VAR** technology recently. I want to know the list of sensors that are approved by FIFA till now.

Comment: As listed in the link? List them here please. The question should be complete.

Answer (score 1):

The [Laws of the game](http://www.theifab.com/laws/the-players-equipment/chapters/other-equipment) allow only specific gear:

> Players (including substitutes/substituted and sent off players) are
>   not permitted to wear or use any form of electronic or communication
>   equipment (except where [EPTS](https://football-technology.fifa.com/en/media-tiles/epts/)* is allowed). The use of any form of
>   electronic communication by team officials is not permitted except
>   where it directly relates to player welfare or safety.

`*` Electronic performance and tracking systems

And if EPTS are allowed:

> Where wearable technology (WT) as part of electronic performance and
>   tracking systems (EPTS) is used in matches played in an official
>   competition organised under the auspices of FIFA, confederations or
>   national football associations, the technology attached to the
>   player’s equipment must bear the following mark:
>
> [image]

So (except for health and safety devices) only EPTS devices are allowed in certain competitions and they must have that mark. Anything else is forbidden.